# How to assign a letter to my project path?

Tags: c#, path, tilde

Instead of doing this every time

```
String[] subject = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\VVIT\\Downloads\\notifications\\Mynotifications\\subjects.txt");
```

Just need to do this:

```
String[] subject = File.ReadAllLines("~\\notifications\\Chairman\\subjects.txt");
```

Whenever I change the project drive, the tilde ~ must automatically fetch the project path.

Answer (score 0):

Don't depend on relative path. Relative path depends on "Current Directory" which can be retrieved in .net by `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Current Directory may change through the lifetime of your program. For instance `OpenFileDialog` can change `CurrentDirectory`, starting your application from command prompt with different location can change it as well.

I'd recommend you to have a base directory then combine your relative path to generate a absolute path.

```
string baseDirectory = ...;
string myAbsolutePath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory , @"\notifications\Chairman\subjects.txt");
```

Comment: @sivavvit this was answered last year :\ There are couple of answers here. If your question is answered and you're convinced with the answer, you should accept the answer which helped you.